# Can i run "DemoteNewsArticle" & "CommentsEnabled" commands without altering the ModifiedBy and Modified fields and without sending users alerts

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, administration, pnp-powershell, modern-experience

I am working on a SharePoint online classic team site. and from time to time I run these remote power-shell commands:-

1- To un-post a modern page from being shown as News:-

```
$clientSidePage = Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "TEST-PAGE.aspx"
$clientSidePage.DemoteNewsArticle()
```

2- To disable comments on a modern page:-

```
$cred = Get-Credential  
Connect-PnPOnline -Url hhttps://*.sharepoint.com/ -Credential $cred  
Set-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "test-page.aspx" -CommentsEnabled:$false
```

now the first command will cause the ModifiedBy + the Modified fields to be updated. where the second command will cause the ModifiedBy field to be updated. also both commands will cause users' alerts to be sent (when users set the alert on every change).

so can i modify my above 2 commands, so the ModifiedBy and the Modified fields will not get updated? also to prevent users' alerts from being sent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To un-post the Modern page from being shown as News without changing the modified and modifiedby fields, you can do as below:

```
$clientSidePage = Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "TEST-PAGE.aspx"

Set-PnPListItem -List "Site Pages" -Identity $clientSidePage.PageListItem.Id 
-Values @{"PromotedState"=0} -SystemUpdate
```

Basically, we are setting the property `PromotedState` to 0 and updating it using `SystemUpdate` method.

2) To disable comments, you can do so as below:

```
$clientSidePage = Get-PnPClientSidePage -Identity "TEST-PAGE.aspx"

$listItem = $clientSidePage.PageListItem;

$listItem.SetCommentsDisabled($true)

$listItem.SystemUpdate()

Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Comment: looks like it is working 100% .. thanks a lot. also no users' alerts are been sent which is great..